# Traverse Mat as 64x64 per iteration

Tags: c++, opencv

Good day,

I am looking for a nested for loop to traverse the image of size 512x512 as 64x64 per iteration. My goal is to determine the element of each sub-region, such as performing number of edge count.

In this following code, I have tried to iterate per 64 row and 64 col (expect 8 times each to hit 512). Within the nested for loop, I have placed vec3b as a test run and I aware that the entire cycle of my code is repeating an identical pattern rather than traverse entire image.

```
int main()
{
char imgName[] = "data/near.jpg"; //input1.jpg, input2.jpg, near.jpg, far.jpg
Mat sourceImage = imread(imgName);
resize(sourceImage, sourceImage, Size(512, 512));

for (int t_row = 0; t_row < sourceImage.rows; t_row += 64)
{
    for (int t_col = 0; t_col < sourceImage.cols; t_col += 64)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 64; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 64; col++)
            {
                Vec3b bgrPixel = sourceImage.at<Vec3b>(row, col);
                cout << bgrPixel << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: a quite elegant way would be to create a cv::Rect in reach iteration and iterate over 0..64 of the subimage covered by that cv::Rect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to have `64x64` sub-images per iteration, make use of OpenCV's [`Rect`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html), like so:

```cpp
const int w = 64;
const int h = 64;

for (int i = 0; i < int(sourceImage.size().width / w); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < int(sourceImage.size().height / h); j++)
    {
        cv::Mat smallImage = sourceImage(cv::Rect(i * w, j * h, w, h));

        // Pass smallImage to any function...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over

```
Vec3b bgrPixel = sourceImage.at<Vec3b>(row, col);
```

with 0 <= row < 64 and 0 <= col < 64. You are right that you iterate 64 times over the same region.

It should be

```
Vec3b bgrPixel = sourceImage.at<Vec3b>(t_row + row, t_col + col);
```